# You have a new answer (?)

Tags: discussion

While I was editing an answer to a question, a dark blue bar with yellow letters appeared at the top of the screen saying "You have a new answer."  I don't know what this means unless it's that someone has just posted an answer to a question that I posted.

But the bar disappeared in a few seconds.  I didn't pounce on it because I was doing something else that would have been interrupted.  I didn't even attend very closely to what it said, because I was doing something else that would have been interrupted.

How does the idea that one should rush to attend to such things in a fraction of a second make sense?

Is there some way I can find out what the thing said after it's disappeared?

Comment: My guess is that the bar disappeared once the page updated to display the new answer (which I believe can occur even without refreshing the page). But I'm not sure.

Comment: There is such a notification when a new answer has been posted while you are composing an answer. Perhaps that's what you saw?

Comment: I think the "you have a new answer" isn't announced by a bar (at least I never received such a banner); only by a notification in your inbox, so I suspect Bill is right. On the other hand: I'd most welcome this evanescent behavior of the notification "you have earned a new badge" that you can't even click away anymore but you're forced to visit your profile...

Comment: Could you provide a link to the post you were editing?

Comment: I suspect very strongly that what you actually saw was the "1 new answer has been posted" message that appears when someone posts an answer to the question you're answering (as Bill mentions).

Comment: If that's the message you saw, then it lasts at least a few seconds (not a fraction of a second unless you mean a fraction like $53/9$). And it's *meant* to interrupt what you're doing, because for instance it's likely that the other answer already said what you were going to say, and you can cancel yours and save the time it would take to finish your answer. (Or perhaps you can incorporate something it says!)